# How would I create a pause menu in ARSKView?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I am creating an Augmented Reality Sprite Kit game using Swift, and I am looking to implement a pause menu. I have tried to adapt the code seen in [Layer for pause menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464602/layer-for-pause-menu) but to no avail.

I have been able to get the ARSKView to pause using ***sceneView.isPaused = true***, but that's all - my pause menu layer doesn't appear.

Comment: Do you want the pause menu to be a "2D" screen above the current AR content? Or do you want the pause menu to appear in the AR world?

Comment: @nathan a 2D screen that appears on top of the AR content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a `pauseNode` like you normally would in `SpriteKit`, instead create another view above the `ARSKView`.

Either in your storyboard or view controller, add another view that is pinned to be fullscreen. This can either be a `UIView` or an `SKView`, depending on whether you would like to use `UIKit` or `SpriteKit` to create your menu (labels, buttons, etc). I would recommend using `UIKit`, since it is designed for building user interfaces.

The view hierarchy would look something like this:

```
-- UIViewController
    -- UIView / SKView
    -- ARSKView
```

---

To communicate between these views, set up a pause menu delegate to notify your view controller when buttons are pressed.

```
protocol PauseMenuViewDelegate: class {
    func pauseMenuUnPauseButtonPressed()
}
```

In your pause menu view:

```
class PauseMenuView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: PauseMenuViewDelegate?

    @IBAction func unPauseButtonPressed() {
        delegate?.pauseMenuUnPauseButtonPressed()
    }

    ...

}
```

In your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pauseMenuView: PauseMenuView! {
        didSet { pauseMenuView.delegate = self }
    }

    ...

}

extension ViewController: PauseMenuViewDelegate {

    func pauseMenuUnPauseButtonPressed() {
        // unpause the game here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it looks like the storyboard won't let me have both an ARSKView and a UIView in the same ViewController - dragging one into both the Storyboard and the Hierarchy just overwrites the other...

Comment: @podomunro Did you start from the default AR template?

Comment: Yes I did - I haven't changed anything else.

Comment: Delete the current view controller and drag a new one. You'll need to 1. Set it as the initial view controller 2. Set its custom class to your view controller 3. Drag an ARSKView and set its constraints, and 4. Drag a UIView and set its constraints.

Comment: Done, and it works. I've also had to make the pause button a UIButton in the storyboard rather than as an SKSpriteNode in my scene. Thanks!